# How to listen to localhost traffic via a web socket server in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, url-shortener

I am trying to implement a URL shortener in Python in a very core way without using any web frameworks like FLASK or Django, to better learn how web sockets work.
I have created a client script which connects to the server via a socket which listens on localhost on port 80. The server then shortens the URL by an algorithm which shortens the URL to https://127.0.0.1/something and sends it to the client, and also stores it in a database. So far, this is the most basic message exchange interactions done by a client-server using sockets.

Now what I want to do is whenever I enter the shortened URL in the browser i.e. https://127.0.0.1/something, it should be captured by the server socket running on localhost. Is it possible? If so, How? I only need an idea of what I can do, but pseudo codes can be helpful as well.

~Regards

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. the server can be done in python with sockets and here is the code.

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)

PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

s.bind((HOST, PORT))

s.listen()

conn, addr = s.accept()

with conn:

print('Connected by', addr)

while True:
data = conn.recv(1024)
if not data:
break
conn.sendall(data)
```

this code works as you want it and can be edited. first we define the host and the port with the localhost IP and the port you want to listen. then it creates a socket to listen on this address:port and when a connection comes, it will print the IP Address of the connected client and then listens for a message from the client. after it recieves the message, you can run the algorithm and return your value back to the client.
Note: this is an incomplete code for you so you need to add your algorithm and return values but besides that, it works beautifully.

Comment: So I tried your code, ran the server, but when I try to open https://127.0.0.1:65432 on google chrome, it says:
 
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 1031)
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  
  File "server.py", line 18, in <module>
    data = conn.recv(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Comment: yes. it connected fine BUT  this is a TCP sockets listening for simple data, the error you got means that the google chrome is using it in an HTTP manner which is not compatible with this kind of server.

Comment: I have modified the code a bit, now i can capture the incoming request. The http request works fine, but the https request seems to be encoded in such a way i cant seem to decode. I have tried msg.decode("Latin-1"), msg.decode("Ascii"), msg.decode("unicode_escape") but still not able to read the https request. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: for the most part, you cannot decode the https traffic to be fully plain text BUT you can play with it enough, once you get the message, try msg.decode("utf-8") and then print the output and you should see some http(s) headers